# Как растянуть блок на всю высоту страницы(до дна прокрутки)?

Tags: html, css, веб-сайт

Как растянуть блок по высоте так, чтобы он был до самого низа прокрутки страницы, а не только высоту вьюпорта?

```css
.area{
    background: rgb(azure);  
    background: rgb(azure);  
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(54, 54, 54);
    animation: bg-animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
    
}

.circles li:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;
}



@keyframes bg-animate {

    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateY(-100rem) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="area" >
            <ul class="circles">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
            </ul>
    </div >
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так?

```css
/* Начала кода */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* Конец кода */

.area {
  background: azure;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54);
  animation: bg-animate 25s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 85%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 11s;
}

@keyframes bg-animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100rem) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <ul class="circles">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Или можете упростить ваш код следующим образом

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.area {
  background: azure;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);
  left: var(--l);
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54);
  animation: bg-animate 25s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: var(--delay);
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
  bottom: -150px;
}

@keyframes bg-animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100rem) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <ul class="circles">
    <li style="--w: 80px; --h: 80px; --l: 25%;--delay: 2s; --duration: 0s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 20px; --h: 20px; --l: 10%;--delay: 2s; --duration: 12s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 20px; --h: 20px; --l: 70%;--delay: 4s; --duration: 0s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 60px; --h: 60px; --l: 40%;--delay: 0s; --duration: 18s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 20px; --h: 20px; --l: 65%;--delay: 0s; --duration: 0s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 110px;--h: 110px;--l: 75%;--delay: 3s; --duration: 0s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 150px;--h: 150px;--l: 35%;--delay: 7s; --duration: 0s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 25px; --h: 25px; --l: 50%;--delay: 15s;--duration: 45s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 15px; --h: 15px; --l: 20%;--delay: 2s; --duration: 35s"></li>
    <li style="--w: 150px;--h: 150px;--l: 85%;--delay: 0s; --duration: 11s"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё равно не растягивается, мне это нужно для мобильной версии сайта и там эта анимация начинается где-то через 30% от начала страницы и высота у нее будто просто 100%